# Passing value from one function to another function in C

Tags: c, function, variables

I'm attempting to pass a value determined by one function to another function that comes after it. Essentially: Function 1 determines a value, lets say x. Then X is passed to another function that specifically displays X as text. It's in a separate function to be used by other functions who can also determine the value of X. However, i'm only getting 0 instead of the variable x. What is wrong here?

```
float fahToCel(int userInput)
{
    float result = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("\nPlease input your number in Fahrenheit units:");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
    } while (result = 0);
    result = (float)(((float)5.0f / (float)9.0f) * (float)(userInput - 32));
    return result;
}

float celToFah(int userInput){
    float result = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("\nPlease input your number in Celcius units:");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
    } while (result = 0);
    result = (float)(((float)9.0f / (float)5.0f) * (float)(userInput + 32));
    return result;
}

float displayResult(float result) {
    printf("\nThe equivalent tempature is: %f\n", result);
    return result;
}

void inputInformation() {
    printf("1. Convert temperature input from the user in degrees Fahrenheit to 
    degrees Celsius.\n");
    printf("2. Convert temperature input from the user in degrees Celsius to 
    degrees Fahrenheit.\n");
    printf("3. Quit.\n ");
}


int main()
{
    int menuChoice = 0;
    int userInput = 0;
    int result = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        inputInformation();
        printf("Please make a selection now:");
        scanf("%d", &menuChoice);

        switch (menuChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                 fahToCel(userInput);
                 displayResult(result);
                 break;
            case 2:
                 celToFah(userInput);
                 displayResult(result);
                 break;
            case 3:
                 return 0;
            default:
                 printf("\nThat is not a choice!\n");
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass `userInput` to the functions you call, instead of declaring them inside the functions as local variables?

Comment: Also learn the difference between assignment using `=` and comparison for equality using `==`.

Comment: Finally, ***where*** inside your loops do you set the value of `result`?

Comment: Also `while(result=0)` should be `while(result==0)`

Comment: Unrelated, tone down the casts Ex: that `fahToCel` expression requires exactly *none* of the burden of casts you're littering within that expression. Casting isn't something you're paid for by the unit count, so avoid it unless it's mandatory (and strongly question whether it's mandatory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assign the result to `result`. Change like this:

```
result = fahToCel(userInput);
displayResult(result);
```